# installing libgconf-2-4 on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, discord, deb

Today I made a ubuntu bootable on an usb drive. I wanted to download discord for my ubuntu and downloaded the file from the discord website. However when I tried to install i got missing dependencies error. The error is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of discord:
 discord depends on libatomic1; however:
  Package libatomic1 is not installed.
 discord depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
 discord depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.
 discord depends on libc++1; however:
  Package libc++1 is not installed.
```

When i tried to install libgconf-2-4  i got another error:

```
Package libgconf-2-4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgconf-2-4' has no installation candidate
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I had the same issues when downloading the file directly from the discord website. I ended up following this https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-discord-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: Probably `sudo add-apt-repository universe` ............ and `sudo apt update` .... to install "universe" packages https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libgconf-2-4

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and i did it with below two commands

```
apt install libgconf-2-4
```

if it is broken then execute below command

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm on ubuntu version 23.10, and the solution I found was to manually install these deb packages and unpack them in the following order:

- `sudo dpkg -i gconf2-common_3.2.6-5_all.deb`
- `sudo dpkg -i libgconf-2-4_3.2.6-5_amd64.deb`
- `sudo dpkg -i sdkmanager_2.0.0-11405_amd64.deb`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 and command below fixed it for me

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 0):

while installing it it shows this

```
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian oldstable/main amd64 libgconf-2-4 amd64 3.2.6-7 [428 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian oldstable/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1 [232 kB]
```

there fore hence:

```
cd etc/apt/sources.list
```

is the problem when you comment out or when the command below is not included in your souces

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian oldstable main non-free contrib
```